# How to divide a Dataframe with another of different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I got this dataframe

```
print(tablaFrecuencias)
       i=gramos   100   120   150   170   190   200
    0  Manzanas  2000  1450  1000   550     0     0
    1     Mango     0   250   750  2000  1000     0
    2      Pera     0     0     0   350   650  1000
```

And I have to get the probability of each cell so I got this new one

```
totalFrutas = pd.DataFrame(totalFrutas)
print(totalFrutas)
     0
0  5000
1  4000
2  2000
```

Now I want to divide the first one in the second one like this

```
2000/5000 1450/5000...
0/4000 250/4000...
0/2000 0/2000...
```

Try to do this but it gave me this

```
probabilidadCardinalidad = tablaFrecuencias.div(totalFrutas, axis=0)
print(probabilidadCardinalidad)
    0  100  120  150  170  190  200 i=gramos
0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
1 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
2 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
```

This is my full code

```
tablaFrecuencias = pd.read_csv("BY.csv",header = 0)

totalFrutas = tablaFrecuencias.sum(axis=1)
print(totalFrutas)
totalFrutas1 = totalFrutas.sum(axis=0)
print(totalFrutas1)

probabilidadFruta = totalFrutas.div(totalFrutas1)

totalFrutas = pd.DataFrame(totalFrutas)
print(totalFrutas)

x = tablaFrecuencias.select_dtypes('int').columns.tolist()
tablaFrecuencias[x] = 
tablaFrecuencias.select_dtypes('int').div(totalFrutas.values)
print(tablaFrecuencias)
```

Comment: Hi Juancho, you are in Stackoverflow, this question is more appropriate for Stackoverflow in Spanish (https://es.stackoverflow.com), please ask on that site.

Comment: i change it maybe u can help me instead closing it

Comment: @JuanchoPancho Sure, meanwhile can you also change the title in `English`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select only `int` columns using [`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html). Then use [`df.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) to divide by `index`:

```
In [96]: x = tablaFrecuencias.select_dtypes('int').columns.tolist()
In [98]: tablaFrecuencias[x] = tablaFrecuencias.select_dtypes('int').div(totalFrutas.values)

In [99]: tablaFrecuencias
Out[99]: 
   i=gramos  100     120     150    170    190  200
0  Manzanas  0.4  0.2900  0.2000  0.110  0.000  0.0
1     Mango  0.0  0.0625  0.1875  0.500  0.250  0.0
2      Pera  0.0  0.0000  0.0000  0.175  0.325  0.5
```

Comment: i literally copy the same code and the output is this


i=gramos       100 120 150 170 190 200
0 Manzanas 2000 1450 1000 550 0 0
1 Mango 0 250 750 2000 1000 0
2 Pera 0 0 0 350 650 1000

first tablaFrecuencias dataframe

Comment: i added the full code can you try to run it its python 3.8

Comment: it works on ubuntu and i dont know why it doesnt in windows, thank you bro